# WP Web Scraper not Working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a Plugin(WP Web Scraper) with Wordpress 3.6.1 on Wamp server where it is Working .But when I am trying same configuration on Web server(Go daddy Hosting),it is showing error :
**Web Scraper could not fetch content - may not function properly**

Can some one help me ..Why its is working on local server and not on Godaddy hosting server.

```
function wpws_debug() {
    $url_content = wpws_get_content('http://google.com/','title','','on_error=error_show&cache=10&timeout=2');
    if ( strpos($url_content,'Error ') !== false ) {
        return 'Fatel error: WP Web Scraper could not fetch content - may not function properly';
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check the following `ini_get('allow_url_fopen')`? if not allowed, most likely your problem may lie here, and you need to check with your provider.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the WP Web Scraper library it's impossible to know exactly whats going on but I suspect GoDaddy is not allowing you to run some privileged function like `file_get_contents();`

Many shared hosts will not allow you to perform such actions as they are (quite rightly) concerned about possible security exploits.

If you want to do things like web scraping you may have to look at cloud hosting or a virtual server

Answer (score 0):

The functon `wpws_get_content` in wp-web-scraper uses the native WordPress function `wp_remote_request`. The above message means that your Godaddy hosting environment is not allowing http requests OR possibly if you are on shared hosting, Google has banned that particular machine's ip (`wpws_debug` just pings Google to test the setup). If Google has banned the IP, you may still be able to scrap other sites.

**Note:** I am the author of wp-web-scraper. Please write to me at akshay(dot)raje(at)gmail if you need any specific help with this.